# Why I can't use the time command in verbose mode without specifying the whole command path?

Tags: time

Given that...

```
~$ which time
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time
```

Why this works?

```
~$ /usr/bin/time --verbose ./some_script.sh 
Command being timed: "./some_script.sh"
User time (seconds): 0.00
System time (seconds): 0.01
Percent of CPU this job got: 51%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.03
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 4572
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 1
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 1548
Voluntary context switches: 3
Involuntary context switches: 7
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 48
File system outputs: 0
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

And why this doesn't?

```
~$ time --verbose ./some_script.sh 
--verbose: no se encontró la orden

real    0m0.124s
user    0m0.101s
sys 0m0.022s
```

Answer (score 10):

When you invoke a command without specifying path to it, others shell alias, function, builtin with the same name will be invoked, instead of command. This behavior was [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01).

In order to call external `time` command, you can use [command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html):

```
command time --verbose cmd
```

Comment: Also note that using "command" this way may not work the same in a non-interactive shell.  To work under nohup for example I gave up on command and used this form instead:  nohup /usr/bin/time --verbose echo &

Answer (score 4):

Because /usr/bin/time and the time built into your shell are completely different implementations.  Run `help time` to get the usage of the one built into your shell, and obviously `man time` for the one in `/usr/bin/time`.